# Is there any difference between standby, suspend and off DPMS modes on LCD dislays?

Tags: lcd, dpms

All three of these modes seem to have the same effect on my display. Same blanking and waking time. Are there any differences in power consumption or something else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On an LCD display, there is probably no difference between the different DPMS modes, which are really [specified for CRTs](http://webpages.charter.net/dperr/dpms.htm).

From [Saving Power on idle PCs](http://saf.bio.caltech.edu/saving_power.html):

> … for an LCD display there is often no difference between standby, suspend, and off.

Comment: Thanks, didn't expect someone answers the question after so long.

Comment: @modular That Necromancer achievement soooo shiny ;)

Comment: I found a difference. Standby is the only mode which actually displays an image after I power cycle the monitor manually via its power button. The other modes, Suspend and Off, just remain blank/black when I restart the monitor, even when I move the mouse or press a key. So there's a difference. At least this is the case on my Linux installation.